# R count parts of same characters in vector

Tags: r, vector, count

I've a vector, that consist only from 0 and 1, for example:

```
 a<-c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1)
 b<-c(0,0,1,1)
 c<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1)
 d<-c(1,0,0,1,0,1)
```

How to count, how many times in a vector appears sequences of 0?

It means that for vector **a** I expect answer 3.
For **b** - 1, **c** - 3, **d** - 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `rle`:

```
sum(rle(a)$values==0)
```

For all a,b,c,d:

```
sapply(list(a,b,c,d),function(x)sum(rle(x)$values==0))
[1] 3 1 3 2
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer greatly :) Thank you!